Importing layer data to QGIS from UMAP and converting it into correct Coordinate Reference System
I have drawn some polylines in the UMAP and saved them as a layer. Later, I figured out that QGIS is more suitable for my project. Then, I am trying to export the data from UMAP to QGIS. The data can be exported as GeoJSON, GPX, KML and CSV. However, after importing it into QGIS and setting the CRS to EPSG:2326 (usually used in Hong Kong), the location is all wrong. I don't know the exact Coordinate Reference system of the UMAP used.
The Latitude and Longitude in the CSV look like:

How would I convert the GeoJSON/CSV data or project the correct CRS into QGIS?

Try setting it to 4326, but the longitude looks odd, normally Hong Kong would be positive and less than 180

EPSG is not synonymous with CRS, some CRS have no equivalent EPSG CRS code.  including both the CRS used for GeoJSON, and the CRS used by KML.  If you have longitude values greater than +/- 180 then you haven't got EPSG:4326, CRS84, or LonLat84_5773.  If you have decimal degrees then you haven't got EPSG:2326, because it uses metres not degrees as unit of measure

Add 360 to the longitude values and you should get the -180/+180 range standard values.

@mkennedy Yes! It works fine! Would you mind posting it as an answer so I could select it to be settled down?

@Light Thanks! Answer added, and I'm glad it worked for you.

The longitude values are in a -360 to 0 range, rather than the usual -180 to +180 range. Add 360 to each longitude value and that should line up the data properly.
